# Matrices in Netlogo: how to multiply a column vector by a matrix?

Tags: matrix, netlogo

This may be very obvious, but how do you multiply a column vector by a matrix? For example:

```
let n matrix:from-column-list [[1 0]]
let m matrix:from-row-list [[1 0] [0 1]]
```

Using `matrix:times` does not work as the dimensions are not the same, and I can't find any other way of doing it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is not commutative.  This works fine:
`let n matrix:from-column-list [[1 0]] let m matrix:from-row-list [[1 0] [0 1]] show matrix:times m n`

hth